# Identify band inside lane (gel electrophoresis)

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, image-processing

I have this image obtained with the gel electrophoresis.

[image]

I must recognize the bands inside the image. This is an example of what I need

[image]

I've tryed to use a global threshold to obtain a black and white image and then the CCL algorithm to identify the black connected pixels.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm

The white and black image is too far from what I need so the result is not good.
I prefer to avoid to set a threshold for each band beacuse this is time consuming for the user.
Does anyone suggest an idea or does anyone suggest how modify the ccl algorithm to manage this case? 
Thank you

Comment: Try smoothing/thresholding and then Canny edge detection. You may need to play for best threshold values to get you bands.

Comment: @Pervez: Hi, have you tryed? Because I've tryed to use Canny but the result is not very good for me. I've tryed using thi algorithm http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C

Comment: Hi @Martina, Yes I did a quick experiment. I use OpenCV with C++. You may not get desired result directly from canny. You need to give some experiment to find correct parameters of smoothing, thresholding and canny. For smoothing, try median.

Comment: Hi @Pervez, I'm trying (using ImageJ) to set some filters to obtain a better image where I emphasize the weak bands regard to background but the results are not good...